# Multiple ViewModels for a single compose function (Screen)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I am building an app like Gmail with compose. In portrait mode, it only shows the list messages as the main screen of the app, and when the user clicks on one message, the app will navigate to message detail screen. Both screens have a ViewModel: MessagesListViewModel and MessageDetailViewModel.

In landscape mode, I want to show both screens at once, next to each other: on the left side, messages list screen and on the right side, message detail screen of the selected message.

My solution to do that, is that I create a route for message list screen to handle different cases:

- If the app is in portrait mode and no message is selected, it will only show the message list screen
- If the app is in portrait mode and a message is selected, instead of show message list screen, the app with show the message detail screen
- If the app is in landscape mode, it will show both screen.

So basically I have a compose function that handles all this cases. My question here, is it a good practice to have multiple view models in this compose function?

Answer (score 2):

There's unlikely to be one right answer here, but per [State holders and UI State](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders#viewmodel-as):

> **Note:** You should only use `ViewModel` with destination-level UIs. You shouldn't use them in reusable pieces of your UI, such as search bars or Chip groups. In these cases plain classes are better suited.

It sounds like you have a single destination-level UI here which has a different appearance depending on the configuration (landscape / portrait). Therefore, it sounds like a single `ViewModel` would be more in line with the current guidelines.

Comment: They didn't say, use only one ViewModel. They said, use ViewModels only on destination level UIs. I have all ViewModels in the destination levels and then I pass the different ui states and functions to composables

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better solution for this, with just 1 viewmodel that emits the `uiStates` you need, for example

> For Portrait (no message opened) you can emit a `uiState` with just
> the message list
>
> For Portrait (message opened) you can emit a `uiState` with just the
> message details
>
> For Landscape (show both) you can emit a uiState with message details + selected message (to select in the list) + the message list

Since you did not provided any code, I did a little drawing of what I mean, you can just `emit` the data from the `ViewModel`, then observe it in your `Activity / Fragment` and then propagate and open the right composable depending on the uiState.

You can contain these 3 composables inside 1 but for that **you will need to send the 3 uiStates to that composable** and with a when statment decide which composable to open.

I think separating these screen like this will make it much cleaner, also you don't need more than 1 `viewModel`.

[image]

as per @fstanis answer, is it like that, there is no right answer, it depends on what architecture you want to follow and how you want to do it.

From what you describe you can do it both ways

Having 1 `ViewModel` for everything (take care that it could have more code than separating these into different `ViewModels`)

## Benefits

- You contain all these 3 screens into 1 `ViewModel`
- No more instances for any new viewmodel
- You can share data/communicate between these 3 screens with this one `ViewModel`

### Cons

- It could bloat your `ViewModel` with a lot of code (depending on your case)

The other way is to have 1 `ViewModel` per composable, that can separate the logic, but it depends if you need to communicate data between them, if you need to communicate, you will need to send arguments between the navigation of each screen and live the `ViewModels` in the respective composable

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Yes this was my first solution, but then I saw that the view model  is getting really big. That is why I am asking if it is okay to separate the logic to different view models.

Comment: yes, you can separate them, but it will be also better to create 3 different composables and send the respective viewmodels to each one instead of having 1 composable with 3 different viewmodels

Comment: I tried doing that until I started using PagingData. The problem with PagingData that they are flows. When using them, you cannot convert them to state flows with stateIn. You have to use cachedIn, which will return a flow. So when the configuration changes, they will start from the beginning, since they are normal flows and cannot hold the value.